# Trim a string for excess characters c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string shown below and I want to trim the excess forward slashes (i.e // )

so Input is

```
 //
 //
 // Authors
 // Mr. Simmonsen 
 // Mr. Greg
 //
 //
 //
```

And Output should be

```
 // Authors
 // Mr. Simmonsen 
 // Mr. Greg
```

Comment: Where do you get this string from? From a file?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: yes reading from file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trim a `String`:

```
  String source = 
    @"//
      //
      // Authors
      // Mr. Simmonsen 
      // Mr. Greg
      //
      //
      //";

  String result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, source
    .Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Where(line => !line.Trim().Equals("//")));
```

If you want to read a *file*:

```
  String result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\File.txt")
    .Where(line => !line.Trim().Equals("//"))));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is one string, you can remove the carriage returns, split the entries while removing the empty ones, and then join it back together again.

```
var entry = @"//
//
// Authors
// Mr. Simmonsen 
// Mr. Greg
//
//
//".Replace("\r\n","").Split(new[] { '/'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


var newEntry = String.Join("\r\n", entry.Select(x=>"//" + x));
```

Assuming you are getting this from a file and reading one line at a time:

```
var lines = new[]{
"// "
,"// Authors"
,"// Mr. Simmonsen "
,"// Mr. Greg"
,"// "
,"//"
,"//"};

var trimmedLines = lines.Where(x=>x.Trim() != "//");


var nonEmptyLines = String.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, trimmedLines);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] lines = theText.Split(
  new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, 
  StringSplitOptions.None);

string result = string.Empty;

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    if (result != string.Empty)
        result += Environment.NewLine;
    if (!line.Trim().Equals("//"))
        result += line;
}
```